# PyPI Module not working

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, pypi

So today i started working on a simple python module, but i cant make it work.
the module itself works, but when i have uploaded it to PyPI and i then install it using Pip, it wont work.
Please notice that it is built for python-2.7
The source code can be seen here:

> https://github.com/1m0r74l17y/FortyTwo

and it can be downloaded using:

> sudo pip install FortyTwo

whenever i try to run a test program like this:

> from FortyTwo import *
>
> FortyTwo.nope()

It just gives me an error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> > File "test.py", line 3, in
> >
> > > FortyTwo.nope()
>
> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'fortytwo'

I would really appreciate any help, as it might lead me onto what i have to do to fix the problem.

Comment: Your question is too vague. _How_ is it not working?

Comment: i just added some information regarding the problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to do the following.

```
from FortyTwo import fortytwo
fortytwo.nope()
```

If you want to call nope directly from FortyTwo you would need to import that function in `__init__.py`.

e.g.

```
from FortyTwo.fortytwo import nope

def Start():
    """No Clue what to add here"""
```

Comment: so youre saying that if i want to be able to type import FortyTwo and then just say Fortytwo.nope() i would have to add the specific function to __init__.py?

Comment: Yes. You can either just define the function nope inside the init file, define it using import, or probably just do ```from FortyTwo.fortytwo import *```.

Comment: Basically in this case I think it would be easier to just move all your code from fortytwo.py to ```__init__.py```.

Comment: Thanks that was the answer I was looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

What if you do

```
from FortyTwo import fortytwo
fortytwo.nope()
```

* credits to eandersson.

Comment: I can't see how this would work, as that function is not defined in FortyTwo.

Comment: Oeps... Cases confused me! Changed, and credits to you!